# How would an implementation for this UML class diagram look like?

Tags: java, uml

[image: UML Diagram]

```
abstract class Activity extend Measurement extends Location{

private DateTime timestamp;
private int heartRate;

private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private double elevation; 
}
```

I wonder if maybe it should look like this inside, with classes repeated:

```
public class Measurement{
private DateTime timestamp;
private int heartRate;
}

public class Location{
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private double elevation;
}
```

Should it be only all fields or classes inside as well?

Answer (score 1):

You might have misunderstood the black filled diamond, which is not an inheritance but a composition. Your Activity class has no any extends but it contains one instance of Measurement, which has to be instanciated inside Activity.

```
public class Activity {
    private Measurement measurement = new Measurement();
}
```

It should look like this I guess (since I see no constructor in your diagram), although I don't know if measurement should be private or public from your UML diagram.

A better practice of this is to instanciate measurement in Activity's constructor, so I'll just leave [this link here](https://www.journaldev.com/1325/composition-in-java-example) which might help you to understand how to do it.

EDIT : I forgot to mention, your other classes look correct, but don't forget the association relationship between Measurement and Location : Measurement has to know that Location exists. You'll surely have to keep this in mind when adding methods to your current classes.

Comment: Also, there's no `<<abstract>>` class shown in the diagram at all.

Comment: You're totally right, I'm correcting this right now - thanks alot !

Comment: But how about extends? Should it be there? Or should I just do public class Activity {} then public class Measurement {} then public class Location {} OR  public class Activity {} then public class Measurement extends Location {}?

Comment: The keyword extends is only used when a child class inherits from a parent class ; that means you can extend only if you see a white arrow with straight complete line, like in this link : https://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/OOP_Concepts_and_manymore/notation.jpg - but again, you don't have any kind of inheritance arrow in your diagram, so you don't have to add extends. Activity is a class that contains Measurement, and Measurement only knows that Location exists without containing it. Those 3 classes are all simple classes without inheritance.